# Kubernetes metrics server not running

Tags: kubernetes, metrics-server

I have install metrics server on my local k8s cluster on VirtualBox using https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#installation

But the metrics server pod is in

```
metrics-server-844d9574cf-bxdk7      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   28         12h     10.46.0.1      kubenode02   <none>           <none>
```

Events from the pod describe

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                    From                 Message
  ----     ------          ----                   ----                 -------
  Normal   Scheduled       <unknown>                                   Successfully assigned kube-system/metrics-server-844d9574cf-bxdk7 to kubenode02
  Normal   Created         12h (x3 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Created container metrics-server
  Normal   Started         12h (x3 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Started container metrics-server
  Normal   Killing         12h (x2 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Container metrics-server failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  Unhealthy       12h (x7 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  Unhealthy       12h (x7 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Normal   Pulled          12h (x7 over 12h)      kubelet, kubenode02  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.4.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff         12h (x35 over 12h)     kubelet, kubenode02  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   SandboxChanged  55m (x22 over 59m)     kubelet, kubenode02  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          55m                    kubelet, kubenode02  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.4.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         55m                    kubelet, kubenode02  Created container metrics-server
  Normal   Started         55m                    kubelet, kubenode02  Started container metrics-server
  Warning  Unhealthy       29m (x35 over 55m)     kubelet, kubenode02  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  BackOff         4m45s (x202 over 54m)  kubelet, kubenode02  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Logs from the deployment of metrics is as follows using **kubectl logs deployment/metrics-server -n kube-system**

```
E1110 12:56:25.249873       1 pathrecorder.go:107] registered "/metrics" from goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x1942e80, 0xc0006e8db0, 0x1bb58b5)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9d
k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/mux.(*PathRecorderMux).trackCallers(0xc0004f73b0, 0x1bb58b5, 0x8)
        /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apiserver@v0.19.2/pkg/server/mux/pathrecorder.go:109 +0x86
k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/mux.(*PathRecorderMux).Handle(0xc0004f73b0, 0x1bb58b5, 0x8, 0x1e96f00, 0xc0005dc8d0)
        /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apiserver@v0.19.2/pkg/server/mux/pathrecorder.go:173 +0x84
k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/routes.MetricsWithReset.Install(0xc0004f73b0)
        /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apiserver@v0.19.2/pkg/server/routes/metrics.go:43 +0x5d
k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server.installAPI(0xc00000a1e0, 0xc00013d8c0)
        /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apiserver@v0.19.2/pkg/server/config.go:711 +0x6c
k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server.completedConfig.New(0xc00013d8c0, 0x1f099c0, 0xc000697090, 0x1bbdb5a, 0xe, 0x1ef29e0, 0x2cef248, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apiserver@v0.19.2/pkg/server/config.go:657 +0xb45
sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/pkg/server.Config.Complete(0xc00013d8c0, 0xc00013cb40, 0xc00013d680, 0xdf8475800, 0xc92a69c00, 0x0, 0x0, 0xdf8475800)
        /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/pkg/server/config.go:52 +0x312
sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/app.runCommand(0xc0001140b0, 0xc0000a65a0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/app/start.go:66 +0x157
sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/app.NewMetricsServerCommand.func1(0xc000618b00, 0xc0002c3a80, 0x0, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/app/start.go:37 +0x33
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000618b00, 0xc000100060, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc000618b00, 0xc000100060)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:842 +0x453
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc000618b00, 0xc00012a120, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:950 +0x349
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:887
main.main()
        /go/src/sigs.k8s.io/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/metrics-server.go:38 +0xae
I1110 12:56:25.384926       1 secure_serving.go:197] Serving securely on [::]:4443
I1110 12:56:25.384972       1 requestheader_controller.go:169] Starting RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I1110 12:56:25.384979       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I1110 12:56:25.384996       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:130] Starting serving-cert::/tmp/apiserver.crt::/tmp/apiserver.key
I1110 12:56:25.385018       1 tlsconfig.go:240] Starting DynamicServingCertificateController
I1110 12:56:25.385069       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] Starting client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I1110 12:56:25.385083       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I1110 12:56:25.385105       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] Starting client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I1110 12:56:25.385117       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
E1110 12:56:25.385521       1 server.go:132] unable to fully scrape metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from node kubenode02: unable to fetch metrics from node kubenode02: Get "https://192.168.56.4:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.56.4 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs, unable to fully scrape metrics from node kubenode01: unable to fetch metrics from node kubenode01: Get "https://192.168.56.3:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.56.3 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs, unable to fully scrape metrics from node kubemaster: unable to fetch metrics from node kubemaster: Get "https://192.168.56.2:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.56.2 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs]
I1110 12:56:25.485100       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController 
I1110 12:56:25.485359       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file 
I1110 12:56:25.485398       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
```

Comment: Hi there. CrashLoopBackOff  just means it is never "up" and 28 is the number of restarts. The events tell us that it is failing the liveness probe. LP does a check to see if the container is happy. In this case there is something wrong inside the container probably. Try getting the logs from the Deployment with `kubectl logs deployment/metrics-server -n kube-system`. This might tell us why the app in the container is unhappy and reporting unhappy to its livenessProbe.

Comment: Looking at the events further we see that `HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500`. As I'm sure you know 500 is internal server error. So there is probably something wrong in the container. Let's see what the logs say

Comment: @JustinTamblyn added the logs.

Comment: Which K8s version are you using? Have you went thru all the [requirements](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#requirements) needed in order to install metrics server?

Comment: @thomas I am using K8s v1.19.3 and the cluster has been set up using kebeadm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error is due to the **self-signed TLS certificate**. So adding **- --kubelet-insecure-tls** to the **components.yaml** and re-applying it to the K8s cluster fixes the issue.

**Ref:-** https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#configuration

Comment: Just bear in mind that this should not be used in a "production" cluster ie one exposed to real users. The word "insecure" should always be red flag. For just playing around with clusters, or for internal clusters sure, but always be mindful while using this, in case you forget and it ends up used in a prod env.

Comment: I have been trying to use proper TLS for quite a while now, but to the best of my knowledge there are multiple problems stopping me from properly setting the certificates. The repo maintainer isn't helpful, and I got further only because I read the source code itself.

@Oliver If you are using internal IPs won't you have problems with security only if the attacker gets into the cluster? So if they do get in, you already have other problems, and possibly the worst thing they can do is scale up or down the cluster? What is your view?

Comment: Thx a lot. It is in the kind: Deployment part, Path: spec|template|spec|containers|args and is a line like this "- --kubelet-insecure-tls". There has already existed a args section in my file. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml

Answer (score 1):

I think, better would be to reissuing certificates for nodes (workers) and adding IP to SAN.
cat w2k.csr.json

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "w2k",
    "w2k.rezerw.at",
    "172.16.8.113"
  ],
  "CN": "system:node:w2k",
  "key": {
    "algo": "ecdsa",
    "size": 256
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "O": "system:nodes"
    }
  ]
}
```

and commands:

```
cat w2k.csr.json|cfssl genkey - | cfssljson -bare w2k

cat w2k.csr| base64
```

This will output a string to put it in a spec.requet in new yaml file:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: worker01
spec:
  request: "LS0tLS1CRUdJ0tLS0tCg=="
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

Apply it.

```
kubectl apply -f w2k.csr.yaml
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/worker01 configured
```

Approve the csr.

```
kubectl certificate approve w2k
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/w2k approved
```

Get the certificate and put together with its key on a node in /var/lib/kubelet/pki

```
root@w2k:/var/lib/kubelet/pki# mv w2k-key.pem  kubelet.key
root@w2k:/var/lib/kubelet/pki# mv w2k-cert.pem kubelet.crt
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request-object-to-send-to-the-kubernetes-api

Comment: your answer is interesting but what do you mean by `cat w2k.csr.json`, where is that file? I'd love to know why kube-metrics does not work out of the box, is there a setting that I forgot when I created the cluster?

Comment: you need to create it by yourself. This is the input for cfssljson.