# GKE - Metrics-Server - HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

It works for sometime and then it crashes `CrashLoopBackOff`. When it works occasionally I get the `Unauthorized` error. After 5 to 10 minutes, it crashes.

```
Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("Internal Server Error: \"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes\": Unauthorized") has prevented the request from succeeding (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

I'm using the latest version of metric-server.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  27m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/metrics-server-59ff97d56-xjbh4 to gke-test-test-node-pool-05539c92-26z1
  Normal   Created    20m (x3 over 27m)     kubelet            Created container metrics-server
  Normal   Started    20m (x3 over 27m)     kubelet            Started container metrics-server
  Warning  Unhealthy  20m (x7 over 21m)     kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  Unhealthy  20m (x8 over 21m)     kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Normal   Killing    12m (x8 over 20m)     kubelet            Container metrics-server failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled     7m19s (x9 over 27m)   kubelet            Container image "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.4.1" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    2m15s (x71 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

I tried changing settings like suggested by others [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771066/8445363) but none of them work. Any other suggestions?

```
135a136,137
>         - --kubelet-insecure-tls
>         - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
151a154
>           initialDelaySeconds: 300
```

Comment: What is your GKE version?

Comment: Did you made any changes lately on your cluster? Did you changed default metrics-server parameters? What GKE version are you using and did you do any upgrades? Could you provide logs from metrics pod?

Comment: Just to clarify you are using `Google Kubernetes Engine` or you have created Kubeadm cluster using `Google Cloud VMs`?

Answer (score 0):

As OP didn't provide further information I've run multiple scenarios and I was able to reproduce this behavior.

#### Background

OP wants to use newest `metrics-server` version `0.4.1` - [k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.4.1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/tag/v0.4.1).

Please keep in mind that [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview) is special `Google Cloud Platform` product which is integrated with other `GCP` features. It means that apart from being open source `Kubernetes` implementation, it also has some specific configurations and dependencies (not available in open source k8s) which make using those features easier (eg. `Stackdriver`).

Unlike kubernetes clusters built on top of `Google Compute Engine`, `GKE` is fully managed by `Google`.

#### Root cause

All `GKE` versions (stable, rapid channel, static version) are using `metrics-server-v0.3.6` as it's integrated with other `GCP` features.

If you will deploy newest `metrics-server v.0.4.1` you will be able to see that it changed default `GKE` configuration of `serviceAccount`, `Roles`, etc.

```
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server configured
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader configured
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator configured
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server configured
service/metrics-server configured
deployment.apps/metrics-server created
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io configured
```

As those resources, were reconfigured you might get some `Unauthorized` errors.

Another issue is that new version have set `Readiness` and `Liviness` probes.

```
$ kubectl describe po metrics-server-59ff97d56-mp2v2 -n kube-system | grep Liveness:
    Liveness:       http-get https://:https/livez delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
$ kubectl describe po metrics-server-59ff97d56-mp2v2 -n kube-system | grep Readiness:
    Readiness:      http-get https://:https/readyz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
$ kubectl describe po metrics-server-v0.3.6-64655c969-jd5gj -n kube-system | grep Liveness:
$ kubectl describe po metrics-server-v0.3.6-64655c969-jd5gj -n kube-system | grep Readiness:
$
```

#### Conclusion

If you would remove `Readiness` and `Liveness` probe from `metrics-server-v.0.4.1` deployment `YAML` it will be deployed and pod will be in `Running` state, however **IT IS HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED**.
It might disturb work on your cluster in the future or cause some unexpected situations.

If you want to use newest `metrics-server` version you should use `Kubeadm` with [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/).

As additional information, you can rise a `Feature Request` on `Public Issue Tracker` to use newest `metrics-server-v0.4.1` on `GKE`. You can do it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com)